# How the function inverted of characterSet works in Swift(5.0)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have example:

```
let stringToCheck: String = "42"
let numbers: CharacterSet = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
let stringIsANumber: Bool = stringToCheck.rangeOfCharacter(from: numbers.inverted) == nil
```

and i have two question

1. How the function `inverted` works? what does it do?
2. what range does `rangeOfCharacter` return?

Comment: So, what this is doing is saying “look for any any non-decimal-digit characters and make sure nothing is found (i.e., that the range is `nil`)”. I.e., make sure there are no non-decimal-digit characters in the string. I.e., make sure that only decimal digits were entered. Note, the name `stringIsANumber` is a tad misleading, though, because an empty string will return `true`. Functionally, this may be desirable, though (e.g. if in `UITextField` `shouldChangeCharactersIn`, where you really want this “either empty string or only digits” logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inverted` means the opposite. For example, if you have only characters `a` and `b` and `c` and a character set consisting of `a`, its inversion is `b` and `c`. So your `decimalDigits` characters set, inverted, means everything that is *not* a decimal digit.

A *range* is a contiguous stretch of something, specified numerically. For example, if you have the string "abc", the range of "bc" is "the second and third characters". The range of something that isn't there at all can be expressed as `nil`.

So the code you have shown looks for a character that is *not* a digit in the original string, and if it *fails* to find one (so that the range is `nil`), it says that the string *is* entirely a number.